# Check if text column is unique before import

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2016

I have a sql database where one of the columns is a varchar value. This value is always unique, it's not decided by me but a 3rd party application that supplies the data, it's length is undefined and is a mixture of numbers and letters. I should add that it's not declared as unique in the database as to my knowledge you can't for a varchar type?

Each week I run an import of this data from a csv file, however, the only way I know how to check if I'm importing a unique value is to loop through each row in the database and compare it to each line in the csv file to check if the corresponding value is unique.

Obviously this is very inefficient and is only going to get worse over time as the database gets bigger.

I've tried checking Google but no to avail, could be that I'm looking for the wrong thing though.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

- Application is written in C#

Comment: The unique value is probably a primary key which does't allow duplication.  What you can do is an insert method which returns the number of rows affected.  If you get a zero returned it means the key is already in the database and is a duplicate.  Then you can do an update query which will replace the row in the database.  You can do the reverse and do an update then if you get a zero then do an insert.  The efficiency depends which occurs more often.  Having duplicates or not having duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at running a MERGE command on SQL instead of an INSERT, which will allow you to explicitly guide action to be taken on a duplicate.

Note that if the unique field is indexed unique, then searching for a value is O(LOG(n)) and not O(n). THis means that overall performance for inserting N values is O(N*Log(N)) and not O(N*N). As N gets large, this is a substantial performance improvement.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, thanks. When I'm next back at work I'll try this approach and see how it goes. If it works I'll mark your answer :)

Comment: Notice that `MERGE` has a negative impact on performance in a high load system (inserts and updates).

Comment: @NielsBerglund: How does that negative impact compare to the reduced network latency and bandwidth consumption of eliminating a round-trip for every candidate insert, when no UPDATES are taking place (so INSERT's only as in OP's scenario)? Details or a link to more info would be nice.

Comment: Merge worked - I ended up going down a different route though but will still mark this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

- Index the table on the unique field.
- Do a 'if exists' on the unique key field value.If it returns a true, the row exists, update the row. If the return is false then this is a new row, insert the row.